# Cannot declare global, static Scanner object without throwing FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner, filenotfoundexception

Basically, I am running a few tests for a simple CLI game I am making, and initially all of my variables/objects were declared at the beginning of the `main()` method. I now have to create a new method that uses some of the same objects/variables, so I decided to move all of my variables out of `main()` and make them static/global. In doing so, I've run into a problem: despite `main()` throwing `FileNotFoundException`, I was getting the following error message:

```
Tests.java:14: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        static Scanner boardReader = new Scanner(board);
```

Here was my code, up to the problematic line:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tests {
    
    // GAME OBJECTS AND VARIABLES

    // The following is used for reading, displaying, and writing to the game board.
    static File board = new File("Board.txt");
    static Scanner boardReader = new Scanner(board);
    static FileWriter boardWriter = null;
    static StringBuilder boardBuilder = new StringBuilder((int)board.length());

    static String boardDisplay = null;  // This String allows boardContents to print in a more readable way.
    static String boardContents = null; // This is Board.txt represented as a String.

    // There are more variables here than shown, but these are the ones relevant to my problem.
    
    // GAMEPLAY

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        boolean gameIsOngoing = true;
        while(gameIsOngoing) {
        
            // boardContents String from boardBuilder StringBuilder
            while (boardReader.hasNextLine()) {
                boardContents = (boardBuilder.append(boardReader.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator()).toString());
            }
            // More irrelevant code here.
        }
    }
}
```

In trying to fix the problem, I tried to put the code utilizing boardReader inside a proper try-catch as shown here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Tests {
    
    // GAME OBJECTS AND VARIABLES

    // The following is used for reading, displaying, and writing to the game board.
    static File board = new File("Board.txt");
    static FileWriter boardWriter = null;
    static StringBuilder boardBuilder = new StringBuilder((int)board.length());

    static String boardDisplay = null;  // This String allows boardContents to print in a more readable way.
    static String boardContents = null; // This is Board.txt represented as a String.

    // There are more variables here than shown, but these are the ones relevant to my problem.
    
    // GAMEPLAY

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        boolean gameIsOngoing = true;
        while(gameIsOngoing) {
        
            // boardContents String from boardBuilder StringBuilder
            try (Scanner boardReader = new Scanner(board)) {
                while (boardReader.hasNextLine()) {
                    boardContents = (boardBuilder.append(boardReader.nextLine() + System.lineSeparator()).toString());
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // More irrelevant code here.
        }
    }
}
```

Which works, but it makes my code feel less readable, as the Scanner object is no longer listed with all of the other objects. I guess my question is, why *didn't* the first code work? Is it possible for something resembling it more to work?

I also want to mention quick that in researching for this question, I saw some things saying it is generally bad practice to have Scanner objects be global/static. I figured that because this particular Scanner isn't gathering user input (and me having no plans on maintaining this relatively simple project post-completion), it wouldn't be too problematic.

Edit: I don't know why but the editor isn't letting me put a "Hello" at the beginning of this post, so here it is... hello everyone :)

Comment: It doesn't matter if main throws an exception. In the 1st example, the scanner is static variable for the Tests class, not for main method. Main is optional, the class doesn't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is error because the exception is not caught. The Scanner instance is created in context of the Tests class, main method is something different, therefore catching it there won't solve the issue.

If you want a work-around, you can try something like this:

```
static {
    try {
        boardReader = new Scanner(board);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. I've made an ugly workaround for now, but thanks regardless.